# Send email with list of active plugins upon activation/deactivation

Tags: plugins, php, functions, email

I'm using Airtable to keep a real-time list of plugins for multiple WP sites, and have an almost-working setup with Zapier emailing new plugin data when a plugin is activated or deleted.

The email is correct upon plugin activation, however upon deactivation the recently-deactivated plugin is still included in the list. Is the plugin list somehow being cached?

Almost-working code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
// send an email on plugin activate / deactivate 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

function urlToDomain($url) {
   return implode(array_slice(explode('/', preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/', '', $url)), 0, 1));
}

function detect_plugin_change( $plugin, $network_activation ) {

    $url = urlToDomain(site_url());

    $the_plugs = get_option('active_plugins'); 
    sort ( $the_plugs );
    foreach($the_plugs as $key => $value) {
        $string = explode('/',$value);
        $plugins .= $string[0] .", ";
    }

    $to = [email address removed];
    $subject = $url;
    $body = $plugins;
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

}
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'detect_plugin_change', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'deactivated_plugin', 'detect_plugin_change', 10, 2 );
```

This sends an email like this:

**To**: [email address removed]

**Subject**: sitename.com

**Body**: admin-menu-editor, display-posts-shortcode, gravityforms, list-pages-shortcode, plugin-central, simple-history, taxonomy-list-shortcode, user-switching, wordpress-seo, wp-scss

Any ideas what needs to be edited so that it works properly upon plugin deactivation? Thank you!

Comment: What about the bulk activation/deactivation case, e.g. if you bulk deactivate 10 plugins, wouldn't that mean 10 emails?

Comment: Yes, an email is sent for each plugin, including bulk activations/deactivations. I'm not that worried about it though - zapier will process them all into Airtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L725) in `/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`

```php
        do_action( 'deactivated_plugin', $plugin, $network_deactivating );
    }
}

if ( $do_blog )
    update_option('active_plugins', $current);
if ( $do_network )
    update_site_option( 'active_sitewide_plugins', $network_current );
```

The options aren't updated until after the hook fires.

You can get around this by using the first parameter to `deactivated_plugin`:

```php
function detect_plugin_change( $plugin, $network_activation ) {

    $url = urlToDomain(site_url());

    $the_plugs = get_option('active_plugins'); 
    sort ( $the_plugs );
    foreach($the_plugs as $value) {
        // Skip the deactivated plugin.
        if ( $plugin === $value ) {
            continue;
        }

        $string = explode('/',$value);
        $plugins .= $string[0] .", ";
    }

    $to = [email address removed];
    $subject = $url;
    $body = $plugins;
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

}
```

*Edit*: You can also get "fancy" and provide more details about the plugins, if needed, using [get_plugin_data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugin_data).